# Axios works for GET but doesn't work for POST and DELETE?

Tags: reactjs, axios, mulesoft

i have an issue that is very confused for me. I have web application created in React and REST API created in Mulesoft 4. Due CORS problems that i have couldn't solve I added proxy in package.json file and everything worked well with GET request. But now, i'm trying to do POST or DELETE request and it doesn't work. Actually it doesn't "hit" my API route when i'm trying to debug on backend. Below i will show you my code, so i hope that you will help me.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "erp-apoteka",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8081/api/",
... 
}
```

Here is my code for axios delete:

```
export const deleteKategorija = (kategorijaId: number) => {
    return axios.delete(`/kategorije/${kategorijaId}`);
};
```

and for post:

```
export const postKategorija = (requestData: Kategorija) => {
    return axios.post<Kategorija>('/kategorije', {
        naziv: requestData.naziv,
        opis: requestData.opis,
    });
};
```

When im trying to log in console my response it says for delete: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE2hD.png)

and when im trying to log in console my response for post it shows me like blank object: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdyLQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this example where I called a POST api call. Hope it helps you.

**[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/post-api-call-2h83u).** Please open network tab to check post call response then you will get successful response under network tab.

**Here is the Code:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function PostCreate() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});

    const handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const {name, value} = target;
        setPost({...post, [name]: value});
        console.log(post);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const createData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        title: post.title,
                        body: post.body,
                        userId: 1
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => console.log(json));
                console.warn(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        };
        createData();
    };
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name='title' value={post.title} onChange={handleChange}
                                   className="form-control" id="title"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="position">Body</label>
                            <input type="text" name='body' value={post.body}
                                   onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="body"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostCreate;
```